# Applying function to dataframe column containing list of elements in each row

Tags: python, dataframe

```
df1['sTFT'] = df1['MI_range'].apply(lambda f:df1[signal.stft(f)])
```

I have a data frame df1 with column 'MI_Range' with 300 rows. Each row contains a list of 1024 elements. I need to find stft of each row and add the result to the next column in the same data frame (df1['sTFT']). I tried with the
above code. Not able to succeed. Any help is appreciated.
Error observed is :

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\signal\spectral.py", line 1743, in _spectral_helper
win, nperseg = _triage_segments(window, nperseg, input_length=x.shape[-1])

IndexError: tuple index out of range

Data is very huge. Only for visualisation, I am making a similar smaller dataframe. Here I have 2 rows instead of 300 rows. Also I have shown 1024 elements in each list as is the case in the dataframe. I need to run a function on each row (signal.stft or matlibplot.plt.psd) which returns list again. This resulting array needs to be added to dataframe.

Input:
df1:
|'MI_range'|
|----------|
|[-10.527, -10.461, -10.315, -10.088, -9.77, -9.36, -8.719, -7.848, -7.046, -6.369, -5.663, -5.044, -4.787, -4.848, -5.108, -5.715, -6.671, -7.751, -8.83, -9.875, -10.692, -11.187, -11.54, -11.611, -11.126, -10.249, -9.373, -8.527, -7.647, -6.839, -6.063, -5.446, -5.338, -5.686, -5.972, -6.143, -6.591, -7.261, -7.791, -8.1, -8.257, -8.242, -8.135, -7.918, -7.46, -6.945, -6.668, -6.51, -6.253, -6.148, -6.455, -7.145, -8.016, -8.924, -9.938, -11.234, -12.775, -14.221, -15.501, -16.711, -17.901, -19.001, -19.868, -20.413, -20.729, -20.911, -20.767, -20.248, -19.512, -18.662, -17.681, -16.668, -15.783, -14.987, -14.278, -13.761, -13.493, -13.211, -12.722, -12.005, -11.034, -9.907, -8.694, -7.264, -5.508, -3.925, -2.963, -2.414, -1.993, -1.929, -2.432, -3.257, -4.299, -5.698, -7.278, -8.808, -10.417, -12.258, -14.24, -16.249, -18.1, -19.454, -20.463, -21.354, -21.766, -21.242, -20.069, -18.82, -17.533, -16.009, -14.311, -12.933, -12.227, -12.008, -11.917, -11.945, -12.301, -12.957, -13.603, -13.94, -14.056, -14.053, -13.775, -13.158, -12.416, -11.598, -10.608, -9.549, -8.505, -7.618, -7.05, -6.656, -6.183, -5.825, -5.762, -5.743, -5.625, -5.525, -5.435, -5.353, -5.384, -5.483, -5.595, -5.728, -5.824, -5.838, -5.862, -5.748, -5.264, -4.526, -3.804, -3.1, -2.204, -1.088, 0.123, 1.346, 2.669, 4.172, 5.9, 7.866, 9.961, 12.128, 14.345, 16.479, 18.39, 20.215, 21.955, 23.249, 24.025, 24.67, 25.42, 26.031, 26.346, 26.537, 26.864, 27.448, 28.131, 28.617, 28.811, 29.056, 29.496, 29.779, 29.675, 29.404, 29.208, 29.008, 28.745, 28.431, 27.969, 27.37, 26.771, 26.138, 25.326, 24.467, 23.68, 22.873, 22.211, 21.914, 21.801, 21.745, 21.945, 22.343, 22.684, 22.983, 23.274, 23.365, 23.232, 22.995, 22.622, 22.095, 21.486, 20.836, 20.153, 19.506, 18.918, 18.339, 17.729, 17.105, 16.613, 16.317, 15.982, 15.477, 15.06, 14.883, 14.76, 14.54, 14.24, 13.784, 13.243, 12.759, 12.153, 11.264, 10.275, 9.433, 8.624, 7.853, 7.177, 6.547, 5.9, 5.168, 4.255, 3.095, 1.734, 0.044, -1.908, -3.863, -5.68, -7.384, -8.86, -9.929, -10.575, -10.819, -10.738, -10.436, -10.133, -9.939, -9.755, -9.574, -9.594, -9.884, -10.171, -10.392, -10.555, -10.503, -10.17, -9.703, -9.081, -8.131, -7.178, -6.442, -5.601, -4.495, -3.631, -3.236, -2.915, -2.493, -2.177, -2.139, -2.405, -2.944, -3.652, -4.514, -5.554, -6.713, -7.853, -8.874, -9.763, -10.523, -11.127, -11.545, -11.824, -12.02, -12.181, -12.376, -12.554, -12.672, -12.792, -12.952, -13.195, -13.588, -14.048, -14.399, -14.758, -15.183, -15.336, -15.028, -14.362, -13.339, -11.897, -10.175, -8.259, -6.239, -4.472, -3.161, -2.211, -1.655, -1.628, -2.004, -2.683, -3.652, -4.641, -5.457, -6.307, -7.233, -7.948, -8.406, -8.776, -9.105, -9.425, -9.722, -9.893, -10.009, -10.206, -10.518, -11.002, -11.626, -12.206, -12.786, -13.469, -14.059, -14.409, -14.501, -14.199, -13.611, -13.06, -12.408, -11.446, -10.614, -10.303, -10.316, -10.438, -10.682, -11.062, -11.606, -12.287, -12.793, -12.878, -12.671, -12.43, -12.176, -11.772, -11.236, -10.739, -10.374, -10.144, -10.109, -10.251, -10.398, -10.497, -10.722, -11.071, -11.363, -11.624, -11.956, -12.234, -12.44, -12.767, -13.12, -13.288, -13.383, -13.518, -13.494, -13.257, -13.027, -12.827, -12.456, -11.888, -11.314, -10.827, -10.407, -10.101, -9.888, -9.659, -9.528, -9.671, -9.968, -10.154, -10.172, -10.085, -9.938, -9.705, -9.272, -8.682, -8.038, -7.353, -6.65, -6.016, -5.444, -4.929, -4.527, -4.147, -3.785, -3.562, -3.433, -3.308, -3.296, -3.366, -3.404, -3.509, -3.718, -3.948, -4.226, -4.468, -4.524, -4.626, -5.081, -5.715, -6.269, -6.826, -7.841, -9.545, -11.406, -12.955, -14.517, -16.342, -17.928, -19.007, -19.631, -19.749, -19.528, -19.189, -18.485, -17.387, -16.391, -15.497, -14.438, -13.342, -12.302, -11.111, -9.808, -8.506, -7.037, -5.485, -3.853, -1.906, 0.297, 2.449, 4.65, 7.198, 9.783, 12.092, 14.098, 15.8, 17.081, 17.913, 18.294, 18.157, 17.702, 17.256, 16.859, 16.375, 15.874, 15.524, 15.424, 15.541, 15.763, 16.003, 16.441, 17.156, 18.001, 18.966, 20.079, 21.241, 22.337, 23.372, 24.247, 24.923, 25.457, 25.799, 25.932, 25.938, 25.913, 25.824, 25.687, 25.602, 25.601, 25.516, 25.357, 25.426, 25.762, 26.068, 26.284, 26.665, 27.29, 28.019, 28.662, 29.155, 29.588, 30.026, 30.335, 30.373, 30.123, 29.659, 29.046, 28.253, 27.198, 25.95, 24.673, 23.332, 21.995, 20.86, 19.954, 19.065, 18.223, 17.662, 17.372, 17.164, 16.877, 16.557, 16.281, 16.073, 15.873, 15.682, 15.512, 15.274, 15.0, 14.844, 14.774, 14.598, 14.344, 14.009, 13.488, 12.88, 12.297, 11.532, 10.47, 9.293, 8.031, 6.671, 5.336, 4.031, 2.601, 1.136, -0.106, -1.089, -1.999, -2.926, -3.745, -4.412, -4.94, -5.395, -5.911, -6.531, -7.052, -7.365, -7.709, -8.148, -8.545, -8.88, -9.257, -9.671, -10.085, -10.576, -11.146, -11.698, -12.15, -12.518, -12.796, -12.951, -13.031, -13.064, -12.995, -12.837, -12.744, -12.687, -12.574, -12.456, -12.28, -11.923, -11.479, -11.077, -10.529, -9.797, -9.042, -8.252, -7.476, -6.889, -6.455, -6.027, -5.775, -5.847, -6.143, -6.65, -7.356, -8.059, -8.653, -9.188, -9.575, -9.661, -9.453, -8.978, -8.229, -7.407, -6.711, -6.158, -5.727, -5.613, -5.992, -6.751, -7.698, -8.78, -9.984, -11.233, -12.518, -13.737, -14.619, -15.103, -15.547, -16.124, -16.624, -16.915, -17.091, -17.282, -17.577, -18.042, -18.53, -18.74, -18.702, -18.664, -18.636, -18.205, -17.231, -16.035, -14.684, -12.997, -10.972, -8.866, -6.738, -4.72, -3.031, -1.606, -0.378, 0.494, 0.907, 0.971, 0.711, 0.099, -0.73, -1.745, -3.038, -4.647, -6.456, -8.348, -10.308, -12.155, -13.71, -15.154, -16.663, -17.879, -18.538, -18.93, -19.304, -19.595, -19.796, -19.792, -19.417, -18.891, -18.526, -18.196, -17.634, -17.011, -16.57, -16.267, -16.002, -15.842, -15.773, -15.604, -15.275, -14.767, -14.019, -13.102, -12.118, -10.96, -9.538, -8.062, -6.786, -5.831, -5.036, -4.183, -3.45, -3.23, -3.472, -3.8, -4.104, -4.56, -5.397, -6.54, -7.588, -8.408, -9.344, -10.539, -11.692, -12.651, -13.567, -14.557, -15.554, -16.414, -17.117, -17.699, -18.2, -18.547, -18.583, -18.3, -17.956, -17.686, -17.17, -16.264, -15.353, -14.789, -14.394, -13.816, -13.125, -12.68, -12.624, -12.736, -12.77, -12.694, -12.649, -12.81, -13.133, -13.322, -13.312, -13.432, -13.828, -14.173, -14.315, -14.543, -14.883, -14.97, -14.673, -14.201, -13.616, -12.861, -11.95, -10.842, -9.574, -8.42, -7.5, -6.49, -5.192, -3.891, -2.763, -1.54, -0.025, 1.656, 3.317, 4.884, 6.4, 8.048, 9.852, 11.549, 13.027, 14.472, 16.055, 17.683, 19.157, 20.392, 21.506, 22.665, 23.851, 24.951, 25.855, 26.637, 27.591, 28.755, 29.709, 30.258, 30.763, 31.345, 31.706, 31.814, 31.746, 31.431, 31.139, 31.18, 31.181, 30.816, 30.561, 30.647, 30.655, 30.403, 29.984, 29.401, 28.758, 28.184, 27.539, 26.838, 26.257, 25.73, 25.202, 24.817, 24.444, 23.861, 22.981, 21.746, 20.336, 19.091, 17.895, 16.313, 14.699, 13.616, 13.15, 13.082, 13.184, 13.367, 13.898, 15.027, 16.22, 17.004, 17.573, 18.154, 18.516, 18.483, 18.138, 17.54, 16.767, 15.922, 15.03, 14.118, 13.397, 13.028, 12.995, 13.205, 13.64, 14.325, 15.249, 16.287, 17.221, 17.903, 18.207, 18.173, 17.929, 17.43, 16.408, 14.908, 13.248, 11.549, 9.622, 7.331, 4.927, 2.665, 0.471, -1.803, -3.912, -5.685, -7.244, -8.631, -9.858, -11.008, -12.114, -13.184, -14.368, -15.664, -16.914, -18.109, -19.195, -20.062, -20.685, -21.093, -21.174, -20.876, -20.238, -19.298, -18.094, -16.631, -14.843, -12.745, -10.516, -8.24, -6.011, -4.013, -2.419, -1.257, -0.606, -0.528, -0.966, -1.89, -3.226, -4.678, -6.026, -7.252, -8.291, -9.101, -9.764, -10.22, -10.283, -10.163, -10.177, -10.344, -10.48, -10.494, -10.442, -10.494, -10.731, -10.903, -10.89, -10.83, -10.799, -10.75, -10.669, -10.488, -10.106, -9.635, -9.137, -8.58, -8.022, -7.463, -6.887, -6.493, -6.431, -6.515, -6.729, -7.179, -7.673, -8.14, -8.754, -9.391, -9.764, -9.998, -10.214, -10.34, -10.421, -10.461, -10.381, -10.282, -10.289, -10.243, -10.089, -9.966, -9.919, -9.865, -9.699, -9.463, -9.36, -9.53, -9.751, -9.825, -9.928, -10.269, -10.775, -11.27, -11.716, -12.063, -12.368, -12.778, -13.204, -13.45, -13.59, -13.716, -13.692, -13.564, -13.494, -13.327, -12.975, -12.701, -12.519, -12.168, -11.716, -11.386, -11.059, -10.598, -10.047, -9.44, -8.859, -8.414, -8.007, -7.527, -7.131, -6.89, -6.7, -6.488, -6.267, -6.04, -5.879, -5.791, -5.656, -5.525, -5.542, -5.711, -5.875, -6.009, -6.199, -6.504, -6.815, -7.06, -7.314, -7.618, -8.019, -8.636, -9.382, -9.987, -10.579, -11.515, -12.66, -13.599, -14.248, -14.755, -15.268, -15.807, -16.169, -16.049, -15.543, -15.061]|
|[-2.944, -3.652, -4.514, -5.554, -6.713, -7.853, -8.874, -9.763, -10.523, -11.127, -11.545, -11.824, -12.02, -12.181, -12.376, -12.554, -12.672, -12.792, -12.952, -13.195, -13.588, -14.048, -14.399, -14.758, -15.183, -15.336, -15.028, -14.362, -13.339, -11.897, -10.175, -8.259, -6.239, -4.472, -3.161, -2.211, -1.655, -1.628, -2.004, -2.683, -3.652, -4.641, -5.457, -6.307, -7.233, -7.948, -8.406, -8.776, -9.105, -9.425, -9.722, -9.893, -10.009, -10.206, -10.518, -11.002, -11.626, -12.206, -12.786, -13.469, -14.059, -14.409, -14.501, -14.199, -13.611, -13.06, -12.408, -11.446, -10.614, -10.303, -10.316, -10.438, -10.682, -11.062, -11.606, -12.287, -12.793, -12.878, -12.671, -12.43, -12.176, -11.772, -11.236, -10.739, -10.374, -10.144, -10.109, -10.251, -10.398, -10.497, -10.722, -11.071, -11.363, -11.624, -11.956, -12.234, -12.44, -12.767, -13.12, -13.288, -13.383, -13.518, -13.494, -13.257, -13.027, -12.827, -12.456, -11.888, -11.314, -10.827, -10.407, -10.101, -9.888, -9.659, -9.528, -9.671, -9.968, -10.154, -10.172, -10.085, -9.938, -9.705, -9.272, -8.682, -8.038, -7.353, -6.65, -6.016, -5.444, -4.929, -4.527, -4.147, -3.785, -3.562, -3.433, -3.308, -3.296, -3.366, -3.404, -3.509, -3.718, -3.948, -4.226, -4.468, -4.524, -4.626, -5.081, -5.715, -6.269, -6.826, -7.841, -9.545, -11.406, -12.955, -14.517, -16.342, -17.928, -19.007, -19.631, -19.749, -19.528, -19.189, -18.485, -17.387, -16.391, -15.497, -14.438, -13.342, -12.302, -11.111, -9.808, -8.506, -7.037, -5.485, -3.853, -1.906, 0.297, 2.449, 4.65, 7.198, 9.783, 12.092, 14.098, 15.8, 17.081, 17.913, 18.294, 18.157, 17.702, 17.256, 16.859, 16.375, 15.874, 15.524, 15.424, 15.541, 15.763, 16.003, 16.441, 17.156, 18.001, 18.966, 20.079, 21.241, 22.337, 23.372, 24.247, 24.923, 25.457, 25.799, 25.932, 25.938, 25.913, 25.824, 25.687, 25.602, 25.601, 25.516, 25.357, 25.426, 25.762, 26.068, 26.284, 26.665, 27.29, 28.019, 28.662, 29.155, 29.588, 30.026, 30.335, 30.373, 30.123, 29.659, 29.046, 28.253, 27.198, 25.95, 24.673, 23.332, 21.995, 20.86, 19.954, 19.065, 18.223, 17.662, 17.372, 17.164, 16.877, 16.557, 16.281, 16.073, 15.873, 15.682, 15.512, 15.274, 15.0, 14.844, 14.774, 14.598, 14.344, 14.009, 13.488, 12.88, 12.297, 11.532, 10.47, 9.293, 8.031, 6.671, 5.336, 4.031, 2.601, 1.136, -0.106, -1.089, -1.999, -2.926, -3.745, -4.412, -4.94, -5.395, -5.911, -6.531, -7.052, -7.365, -7.709, -8.148, -8.545, -8.88, -9.257, -9.671, -10.085, -10.576, -11.146, -11.698, -12.15, -12.518, -12.796, -12.951, -13.031, -13.064, -12.995, -12.837, -12.744, -12.687, -12.574, -12.456, -12.28, -11.923, -11.479, -11.077, -10.529, -9.797, -9.042, -8.252, -7.476, -6.889, -6.455, -6.027, -5.775, -5.847, -6.143, -6.65, -7.356, -8.059, -8.653, -9.188, -9.575, -9.661, -9.453, -8.978, -8.229, -7.407, -6.711, -6.158, -5.727, -5.613, -5.992, -6.751, -7.698, -8.78, -9.984, -11.233, -12.518, -13.737, -14.619, -15.103, -15.547, -16.124, -16.624, -16.915, -17.091, -17.282, -17.577, -18.042, -18.53, -18.74, -18.702, -18.664, -18.636, -18.205, -17.231, -16.035, -14.684, -12.997, -10.972, -8.866, -6.738, -4.72, -3.031, -1.606, -0.378, 0.494, 0.907, 0.971, 0.711, 0.099, -0.73, -1.745, -3.038, -4.647, -6.456, -8.348, -10.308, -12.155, -13.71, -15.154, -16.663, -17.879, -18.538, -18.93, -19.304, -19.595, -19.796, -19.792, -19.417, -18.891, -18.526, -18.196, -17.634, -17.011, -16.57, -16.267, -16.002, -15.842, -15.773, -15.604, -15.275, -14.767, -14.019, -13.102, -12.118, -10.96, -9.538, -8.062, -6.786, -5.831, -5.036, -4.183, -3.45, -3.23, -3.472, -3.8, -4.104, -4.56, -5.397, -6.54, -7.588, -8.408, -9.344, -10.539, -11.692, -12.651, -13.567, -14.557, -15.554, -16.414, -17.117, -17.699, -18.2, -18.547, -18.583, -18.3, -17.956, -17.686, -17.17, -16.264, -15.353, -14.789, -14.394, -13.816, -13.125, -12.68, -12.624, -12.736, -12.77, -12.694, -12.649, -12.81, -13.133, -13.322, -13.312, -13.432, -13.828, -14.173, -14.315, -14.543, -14.883, -14.97, -14.673, -14.201, -13.616, -12.861, -11.95, -10.842, -9.574, -8.42, -7.5, -6.49, -5.192, -3.891, -2.763, -1.54, -0.025, 1.656, 3.317, 4.884, 6.4, 8.048, 9.852, 11.549, 13.027, 14.472, 16.055, 17.683, 19.157, 20.392, 21.506, 22.665, 23.851, 24.951, 25.855, 26.637, 27.591, 28.755, 29.709, 30.258, 30.763, 31.345, 31.706, 31.814, 31.746, 31.431, 31.139, 31.18, 31.181, 30.816, 30.561, 30.647, 30.655, 30.403, 29.984, 29.401, 28.758, 28.184, 27.539, 26.838, 26.257, 25.73, 25.202, 24.817, 24.444, 23.861, 22.981, 21.746, 20.336, 19.091, 17.895, 16.313, 14.699, 13.616, 13.15, 13.082, 13.184, 13.367, 13.898, 15.027, 16.22, 17.004, 17.573, 18.154, 18.516, 18.483, 18.138, 17.54, 16.767, 15.922, 15.03, 14.118, 13.397, 13.028, 12.995, 13.205, 13.64, 14.325, 15.249, 16.287, 17.221, 17.903, 18.207, 18.173, 17.929, 17.43, 16.408, 14.908, 13.248, 11.549, 9.622, 7.331, 4.927, 2.665, 0.471, -1.803, -3.912, -5.685, -7.244, -8.631, -9.858, -11.008, -12.114, -13.184, -14.368, -15.664, -16.914, -18.109, -19.195, -20.062, -20.685, -21.093, -21.174, -20.876, -20.238, -19.298, -18.094, -16.631, -14.843, -12.745, -10.516, -8.24, -6.011, -4.013, -2.419, -1.257, -0.606, -0.528, -0.966, -1.89, -3.226, -4.678, -6.026, -7.252, -8.291, -9.101, -9.764, -10.22, -10.283, -10.163, -10.177, -10.344, -10.48, -10.494, -10.442, -10.494, -10.731, -10.903, -10.89, -10.83, -10.799, -10.75, -10.669, -10.488, -10.106, -9.635, -9.137, -8.58, -8.022, -7.463, -6.887, -6.493, -6.431, -6.515, -6.729, -7.179, -7.673, -8.14, -8.754, -9.391, -9.764, -9.998, -10.214, -10.34, -10.421, -10.461, -10.381, -10.282, -10.289, -10.243, -10.089, -9.966, -9.919, -9.865, -9.699, -9.463, -9.36, -9.53, -9.751, -9.825, -9.928, -10.269, -10.775, -11.27, -11.716, -12.063, -12.368, -12.778, -13.204, -13.45, -13.59, -13.716, -13.692, -13.564, -13.494, -13.327, -12.975, -12.701, -12.519, -12.168, -11.716, -11.386, -11.059, -10.598, -10.047, -9.44, -8.859, -8.414, -8.007, -7.527, -7.131, -6.89, -6.7, -6.488, -6.267, -6.04, -5.879, -5.791, -5.656, -5.525, -5.542, -5.711, -5.875, -6.009, -6.199, -6.504, -6.815, -7.06, -7.314, -7.618, -8.019, -8.636, -9.382, -9.987, -10.579, -11.515, -12.66, -13.599, -14.248, -14.755, -15.268, -15.807, -16.169, -16.049, -15.543, -15.061, -14.751, -14.365, -13.704, -13.013, -12.617, -12.548, -12.636, -12.816, -13.149, -13.602, -14.092, -14.471, -14.606, -14.463, -14.103, -13.424, -12.213, -10.636, -9.049, -7.446, -5.623, -3.747, -2.155, -0.912, 0.12, 0.976, 1.643, 2.106, 2.383, 2.407, 2.298, 2.295, 2.31, 2.004, 1.39, 0.849, 0.406, 0.013, -0.193, -0.325, -0.531, -0.397, 0.381, 1.356, 2.211, 3.156, 4.252, 5.471, 6.828, 8.154, 9.334, 10.483, 11.664, 12.933, 14.367, 15.794, 17.048, 18.375, 19.969, 21.728, 23.557, 25.385, 27.138, 28.805, 30.502, 32.131, 33.404, 34.207, 34.681, 34.905, 34.76, 34.321, 33.717, 32.899, 31.869, 30.881, 30.083, 29.357, 28.725, 28.298, 28.02, 27.804, 27.772, 27.931, 28.063, 28.095, 28.083, 28.03, 27.98, 28.034, 28.0, 27.674, 27.214, 26.874, 26.586, 26.047, 25.116, 23.906, 22.705, 21.611, 20.473, 19.216, 18.009, 17.096, 16.511, 16.157, 15.932, 15.817, 15.861, 16.07, 16.348, 16.601, 16.846, 17.12, 17.402, 17.628, 17.666, 17.457, 17.135, 16.738, 16.078, 15.091, 14.036, 13.125, 12.311, 11.509, 10.753, 10.154, 9.76, 9.482, 9.136, 8.602, 7.92, 7.15, 6.246, 5.181, 4.11, 3.132, 2.142, 1.202, 0.599, 0.35, 0.18, -0.046, -0.325, -0.609, -0.888, -1.337, -2.165, -3.278, -4.488, -5.725, -6.979, -8.313, -9.597, -10.606, -11.371, -12.04, -12.416, -12.339, -12.023, -11.549, -10.924, -10.16, -9.112, -7.727, -6.445, -5.592, -4.739, -3.57, -2.419, -1.661, -1.265, -1.032, -0.783, -0.499, -0.536, -1.012, -1.627, -2.258, -3.092, -4.165, -5.382, -6.729, -8.062, -9.372, -10.691, -11.867, -12.715, -13.387, -14.009, -14.371, -14.411, -14.292, -14.111, -13.793, -13.337, -12.782, -12.125, -11.378, -10.481, -9.355, -8.182, -7.216, -6.338, -5.346, -4.406, -3.825, -3.667, -3.851, -4.084, -4.114, -4.198, -4.653, -5.19, -5.331, -5.13, -4.859, -4.659, -4.558, -4.414, -4.053, -3.556, -3.222, -3.241, -3.443, -3.632, -3.875, -4.445, -5.455, -6.861, -8.565, -10.364, -12.223, -14.188, -16.227, -18.096, -19.53, -20.493, -21.112, -21.476, -21.515, -21.199, -20.595, -19.809, -19.011, -18.185, -17.212, -16.115, -15.002, -13.972, -13.116, -12.462, -11.884, -11.409, -11.252, -11.379, -11.54, -11.639, -11.705, -11.63, -11.32, -10.814, -10.125, -9.353, -8.685, -8.118, -7.531, -7.166, -7.371, -8.013, -8.712, -9.397, -10.231, -11.19, -12.097, -12.764, -13.089, -13.056, -12.769]|

Comment: Hi, Could you add some sample input and expected output?

Comment: Data set is huge. I dont know how to include it here. just for visualization, I have tried to add a small example. I am not sure if it makes the question more complicated.

Comment: What code are you running??  Does it exhibit the same error on your sample dataframe? Please provide an [mre].

Comment: edited to include only 2 rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the specification of the lambda function. Since you are invoking the `.apply` method of `df1['MI_range']` it is operating on a Pandas.Series, on an element-wise basis (i.e., for each row). This means that the argument `f` your lambda function is the list of values in each row.

Assuming that `signal.stft` accept the lists directly, I believe that all you need to do is:

```
df1['sTFT'] = df1['MI_range'].apply(lambda f: signal.stft(f))
```

Comment: still no luck same error: 
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\signal\spectral.py", line 1743, in _spectral_helper
    win, nperseg = _triage_segments(window, nperseg, input_length=x.shape[-1])

IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: I said in my response, "Assuming that `signal.stft` accept the lists directly", because I had not checked the documentation for `scipy.signal.stft`. And it doesn't! Simple fix: convert `f` to an array. `df1['sTFT'] = df1['MI_range'].apply(lambda f: signal.stft(np.array(f)))`

Comment: My mistake. sorry. it worked.

Comment: Sorry, I am not very proficient with Python and data frames throw me off. stft function returns 3 arrays. now my data frame column df1['sTFT'] has 3 arrays (f, t, Zxx) in each row. how do I access each of them? I need to make subarray of Zxx for further calculation. currently Zxx has 300 values which is 3rd array in each row under column df1['sTFT']. I need to pick only 256 values from it. how?

Comment: You can just index the results of stft. If I understand you correctly, all you want are the first 256 values of the third result (index 2) from shft, right? If so, then `df1['sTFT'] = df1['MI_range'].apply(lambda f: signal.stft(np.array(f))[2][:256])`